# Resize image of a TableViewController cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I would like to resize the image of all the TableView cells i have. 
I tried this method and it's working but the quality of the image is decreased.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
//...
         CGSize size = {35,35};
         cell.imageView.image = [self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] scaledToSize:size];
//...

}   

//Given a UIImage and a CGSize, this method will return a resized UIImage.
    - (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
           scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,35,35)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;
    }
```

So i continued searching and i found someone saying to add this method

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,35,35);
}
```

But Xcode gives me an error, is this method not available anymore?

How could i resize the image without losing quality?

Comment: What error does XCode give you?

Comment: By quality is decreased do you mean the image gets blurry?

Comment: @Larme error "no visible interface ... declares the selector layoutSubviews"`

Comment: @CocoaDog exactly! The fact is that in other part of the app i resize the image to 35x35, with good quality, but here get's blurry, guess for the method `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`

Comment: layoutSubviews is a method on UIView, not on UIViewController, where it looks like you're trying to use it.

Comment: The reason why it's blurry is because you're drawing a 35x35 'non retina' image. replace `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize )` with     `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0)` and you should be good.

Comment: nice i found it working too, about the release of the image shouldn't ARC handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find a solution, here i'll explain in case someone will need.

First create a fake image, something like a white image or clear

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clear.png"];
```

That's why you have to tell the cell there's an image.
Now add an `ImageView` as a subview of the `TableView` cell

```
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 35, 35)];
                imgView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                [imgView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
                [imgView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
                [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:account.icon]];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
```

Now it's good. If you don't create the fake image the new created `imgView` will overlap the `cell.textLabel.text`

Comment: You're creating a new image view every time the cell shows and never remove/release them. That'll cause some serious trouble.